# SlickGrid on jQuery UI tabs - navigate to different tab on grid click event

Tags: json, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, slickgrid

I have two separate grids in two jquery UI tabs
1. Summary Tab -Grid1
2. Details Tab -Grid2

I want some help when I click on one of the cell in column from Summary Tab(For eg name) grid1 it takes me to details tab where I will be making separate Ajax call to get detail data from that name.

Code below gets the data item but I am not sure how to navigate to detail tab? Any help will be highly appreciated! New to SLICKGRID

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e, args) {
              var advisorName = grid.getDataItem(cell.row).advisorName; 
            alert("Advisor Name:" + advisorName);
         });
```

For example below: Onclick of id "fullName" (from first GRID) it takes me to that persons detail page GRID 2- DETAILS TAB(Where I am fetching data from another Ajax Call)

Grid 1 --SUMMARY TAB

```
columns : [ {
            id : "fullName",
            name : "Name",
            field : "fullName",
            sortable : true,
            width : 170,
            resizable : true,
            headerCssClass : "contactlist-header",
            formatter : contactFormatter
        }, {
            id : "prefferedEmailAddress",
            name : "Email (Preferred)",
            field : "emailAddress",
            width : 170,
            resizable : true,
            cssClass : "column-email",
            headerCssClass : "contactlist-header header-email",
            formatter : linkFormatter
        }, {
            id : "preferredPhoneNumber",
            name : "Preferred Phone",
            field : "phoneNumbers",
            width : 100,
            resizable : true,
            cssClass : "column-phoneNum",
            headerCssClass : "header-phoneNum contactlist-header"
        }, {
            id : "birthdayStr",
            name : "Birth Date",
            field : "birthdayStr",
            sortable : true,
            width : 110,
            resizable : true,
            cssClass : "column-birthDt",
            headerCssClass : "header-birthDt contactlist-header"
        }, {
            id : "contactId",
            field : "contactId",
            cssClass : "column-nodisplay",
            width : 0,
            minWidth : 0,
            maxWidth : 0,
            headerCssClass : "column-nodisplay"
        }

Grid 2 DETAILS TAB
columns : [ {
            id : "omniAccountNumber",
            name : "OMNI Acct No.",
            field : "omniAcctNumber",
            width : 50
        }, {
            id : "scppAccountNumber",
            name : "SCPP Acct No.",
            field : "scppAcctNumber",
            width : 50
        }, {
            id : "name",
            name : "Name",
            field : "name",
            width : 50
        }, {
            id : "eci",
            name : "ECI",
            field : "eci",
            width : 50
        }, {
            id : "accountTitle",
            name : "Account Title",
            field : "acctTitle",
            width : 50
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to show both grids setup/initalisation, and it's not clear what are you asking about. Currently I think I have answered your question. Is there more to answer? If so please edit your question accordingly.